# Flutter mapbox_gl how to put polylines below symbols

Tags: flutter, dart, mapbox, symbols, layer

I am trying to add polylines to a mapbox view in Flutter using the mapbox_gl library. The problem is that I also have markers (called symbols in the library) that need to be on top of the polylines, but it keeps drawing the polylines over the symbols.

This is the function I use to add the symbols:

```
  _mbController.addSymbol(SymbolOptions(
    geometry:
        LatLng(vehicle['position']['lat'], vehicle['position']['lon']),
    iconImage: 'vehicle'));
```

Then I use these functions to add the polylines:

```
  Future<void> updatePolyLines(var geometry) async {
    _fills = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "id": 0,
          "properties": <String, dynamic>{},
          "geometry": geometry,
        },
      ],
    };

    await _mbController!.removeLayer("lines");
    await _mbController!.removeSource("fills");

    await _mbController!
        .addSource("fills", GeojsonSourceProperties(data: _fills));
    await _mbController!.addLineLayer(
        "fills",
        "lines",
        const LineLayerProperties(
          lineColor: '#007AFF',
          lineCap: "round",
          lineJoin: "round",
          lineWidth: 4,
        ));
  }

  Future<void> showNavLine(LatLng destination) async {
    LocationTuple l = await getLocation(context);
    if (l.gotPosition) {
      var response = await prepareRoute(l.latLng, destination);
      if (response == null) {
        return;
      } else {
        updatePolyLines(response['routes'][0]['geometry']);
      }
    }
  }
```

The prepareRoute function uses the mapbox API to get a route, this part is working fine and the line is shown. However, as I said it is draw on top of the symbols.

I read that you can draw the polylines below a certain layer. So I tried adding a separate layer for the symbols and drawing the polylines below that, but I suspect the symbols are not put on that specific layer. I can't even set a specific layer in the `addSymbol` function of MapboxController.

Please advise. Btw all the examples I found online so far just draw the lines over the symbols. Drawing the lines first and then the symbols doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to put symbols in layers. Also, I was using [lat, lon] while it should have been [lon, lat]..

As long as you add the symbolLayer after the polyline layer the symbols will be drawn on top of the lines. Here is a working example (coordinates have been removed for privacy reasons but the working code is there):

```
var geometry = {
  "coordinates": [
    [lon, lat],
    [lon, lat],
    [lon, lat],
    [lon, lat],
    [lon, lat],
    [lon, lat],
    [lon, lat]
  ],
  "type": "LineString"
};

_fills = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": 0,
      "properties": <String, dynamic>{},
      "geometry": geometry,
    },
  ],
};

await _mbController!.removeLayer("lines");
await _mbController!.removeSource("fills");

await _mbController!
    .addSource("fills", GeojsonSourceProperties(data: _fills));
await _mbController!.addLineLayer(
  "fills",
  "lines",
  const LineLayerProperties(
    lineColor: '#007AFF',
    lineCap: "round",
    lineJoin: "round",
    lineWidth: 4,
  ),
);

await _mbController!.addSymbolLayer(
  "scooter25_layer",
  "vehicles",
  const SymbolLayerProperties(
    iconImage: "scooter25",
    iconAllowOverlap: true,
  ),
);

const Map<String, dynamic> featureCollection = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [lon, lat],
      }
    }
  ]
};

await _mbController!.addGeoJsonSource("scooter25_layer", featureCollection);
```